# Could someone please explain the usage of なる here?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to make sense of a song (純潔なる愛-Aspiration-) and there is this construct of noun+なる that confuses me. I know the "to become" grammar, or になる, but this is missing the に particle and also, it seems like it isn't exactly about becoming something/some way. Here are the lines:

> (1) 純真で孤高なる歌を
>   未来に奏でたい
>
> (2) それは純潔なるAspiration
>
> (3) 届け純潔なるAspiration
>
> (4) 伝え純潔なるAspiration

Now, I see that three out of four are pretty much the same in this regard - but I'm just too confused at this point and want to provide some context. Also, the translation on the fandom Wiki doesn't translate it as "to become", either, just using "to be", as in "this is..." but then, it's poetry.

Could someone please explain? Is it maybe just poetic shorthand or is it a different grammar altogether?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1962/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2994/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43526/9831

Answer (score -1):

なる in this context would mean that whatever on the right is whatever on the left, 
so

1. song of solitude
   2-4. Aspiration of innocence